# В чем разница между return f(n+1) return f(n+2) и return f(n+1) or f(n+2)

Tags: python, рекурсия

Пример кода:

```
def f(x, y, p):
    if x + y >= 142 and p == 3:
        return True
    elif x + y != 142 and p == 3:
        return False
    return f(x + 2, y, p + 1) or f(x * 2, y, p + 1) or f(x, y + 2, p + 1) or f(x, y * 2, p + 1)

for i in range(1, 100):
    if f(2, i, 1):
        print(i)
        break
```

Вывод:

```
35
```

Другой код:

```
def f(x, y, p):
    if x + y >= 142 and p == 3:
        return True
    elif x + y != 142 and p == 3:
        return False
    return f(x + 2, y, p + 1) 
    return f(x * 2, y, p + 1)
    return f(x, y + 2, p + 1)
    return f(x, y * 2, p + 1)

for i in range(1, 100):
    if f(2, i, 1):
        print(i)
        break
```

Вывода нет.

В чем разница между этими кодами и почему разное поведение?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Оператор `or` объединяет условие в виде логического ИЛИ:

> `False` or `True` - будет равно `True`

Причём имеется ряд оптимизаций, если хотя бы одно из условий `or` равняется `True`, то далее не имеет смысла выполнять код

> `return f1() or f2() or f3() or f4()` - если `f1()` вернул `False`, то далее мы выполним `f2()`, если `f2()` вернёт `True`, то `f3()` и `f4()` не будут исполнены, т.к. мы уже определили, что полное условие выдаст `True`

Когда вы пишите несколько `return` подряд, то выполнится только первый и сразу же выйдет из функции, соответственно следующие строки становятся недостижимы.

```
def f(x, y, p):
  if x + y >= 142 and p == 3:
      return True
  elif x + y != 142 and p == 3:
      return False
  return f(x + 2, y, p + 1) # выход из функции
  return f(x * 2, y, p + 1) # недостижимая строка кода
  return f(x, y + 2, p + 1) # недостижимая строка кода
  return f(x, y * 2, p + 1) # недостижимая строка кода
```